# Protractor: sessionStorage variables

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor

How would I get the value of a sessionStorage variable in protractor? I tried:

```
browser.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("login");');
```

but that returns **null**. Using sessionStorage.getItem() without browser.executeScript() returns an undefined for sessionStorage.

Comment: I'm also battling with this requirement. Pls let me know if you've found a solution...

Answer (score 9):

figured it out.

```
browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('login');");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `browser.driver.executeScript` instead of `browser.executeScript`

i.e.

```
browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("login");');
```

Also confirm manually that your javascript expression `sessionStorage.getItem("login");` works fine by using the [browser developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Depending on your app and the steps you are doing to get there, it may be requesting the session storage item too soon. If the `browser.driver.executeScript` doesn't fix your problem try adding a `browser.sleep(4000);` right before the `executeScript` to find out if this is a timing issue.

Note `executeScript` [returns a webdriver promise](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebdriverprototypeexecutescript) so unless you are wrapping that in an `expect` you may need this:

```
browser.sleep(2000);
browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("login");').then(function(retValue) {
    console.log(retValue);
});
```

Comment: I've used the browser developer tools to make sure that the variable is available and it is. I also tried your example but I still got a null value.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite right.  It should be...

```js
browser.driver.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem("login");').then(function (retVal) {
  console.log(retVal);
});
```